# Append uneditable text to end of input?

Tags: html, input, html-input

Does HTML5 have any attributes to append some text onto the end of an input value? For example if I have an `<input type="text">` is there a way I can append something like `/hrs` to then end of the input value?

I could easily do this with JS but it would be included in the final value and would be cumbersome to manage.

Any help or suggestions would be great, thanks!

Comment: show us how you can do it with JS and we'll try to make it less cumbersome for you.

Comment: Why don't you want a constant suffix to be outside the edit box?

Comment: @AndreySScherbakov I wanna try something where it's all included right in the input, I could easily just add a bootstrap addon but I don't wanna do that. Also, with my error validation it doesn't really work to have an addon.

Comment: @mehulmpt It would just be something along the lines of `input.onchange => append string to val`

Comment: @JoeScotto that'll disturb the original cursor position. wouldn't it?

Comment: @mehulmpt That doesn't really matter, it's that I don't want to **add** to the value, I want to add something that is not part of the value but displays in the box.

Answer (score 3):

edited this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43964651/5674442

Here is the code:

```css
input {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.placeholder {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.placeholder::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 1px;
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="placeholder" data-placeholder="/hrs">
    <input value="My text" />  
</div>
```

Comment: Close to what I want but I do not want it to disappear upon typing.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Here you are.

```css
.placeholder {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.placeholder::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 1px;
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="placeholder" data-placeholder="/hrs">
    <input value="My text" />  
</div>
```

Comment: That's a lot closer but I would want it to align with the text for example `33/hrs`